# Extensão cURL não funciona?

Tags: php, libcurl

Quero abrir a página de login de um site que já veio quase todo pronto pra mim, porém este erro acontece:

> Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.
>   Linha 19: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\core\api_classes\facebook\src\base_facebook.php

**Linha 19**

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
throw new Exception('Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.');
```

Fui atrás de saber mais sobre esse `cURL`, e a resolução parecia ser fácil demais pra ser verdade. Precisaria apenas ir no arquivo `php.ini` e tirar o `;` de frente da chamada: `extension=php_curl.dll` e isso não funcionou.

Ao abrir no navegador o arquivo `info.php` e pesquisar sobre o `cURL`, a única informação que aparece é o nome do autor.

O que seria necessário fazer pra que ele realmente funcione?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem... depois que você tirou o `;` ele parou de dar o erro?

Comment: Não amigo. Continuou a mesma coisa, ao tirar o ';' deveria ser instalado a extensão, o que não aconteceu. Eu mudei o arquivo php.ini e nada aconteceu

Comment: Não se engane, remover o caractere `;` apenas **habilita** a extensão, mas se a mesma não estiver instalada, o erro persistirá. No Windows, não sei como é o processo de instalação, então fico te devendo essa, mas acho que o Google pode te ajudar nisso.

Comment: Relacionado á sua dúvida: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php

Comment: Olhando pela sua pergunta, cURL, nem parece estar instalado, uma vez que você somente encontrou o nome do autor. Uma boa opção é dar uma olhada no phpinfo(), na seção cURL support

Comment: @BrunoCastro preste atenção também no php.ini que você editou, pois existe um pro PHP CLI e um pro PHP apache (caso você esteja usando). Como o Saul disse acima, a melhor opção é colocar um `phpinfo()` na página e dar uma analisada na parte do `cURL`.

Comment: Você acredita que esse está acontecendo comigo também... Você achou a solução? Se eu encontrar eu posto aqui

Answer (score -1):

Eu estava tendo esse erro, para corrigi-lo fiz os seguintes passos;

1. Verifique se o seu `php.ini` está retornando algum erro quando você inicia um servidor (Exemplo: `php -S localhost:8080`), caso tenha corrija-o.
2. Tire o comentário (`;`) de `extension=php_curl.dll`
3. Tire o comentário de `extension=openssl`
4. Se você estiver no **Windows** verifique se `extension_dir` está da seguinte forma `extension_dir = "ext"`

**OBS**: No `php.ini` eu estava tendo o seguinte erro:

> Syntax error, unexpected '&' [...]

Para corrigir eu comentei a parte anterior ao `&`, exemplo:

*Antes*

`Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`

*Agora*

`Default Value: E_ALL 
 ; & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`